# Filtering/querying a multi-key btree index in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use a BTreeMap as an index in an in-memory database, with multiple keys. Something like this:

```rust
let mut map = BTreeMap::new();
map.insert(("a".to_string(), "x".to_string()), "ax".to_string());
map.insert(("a".to_string(), "y".to_string()), "ay".to_string());
```

Now my question is, what would be the best way to actually query this? Say for instance I'd like to get ("a", *), i.e. all entries with "a" as the first key and anything as second.

I tried something like this:

```rust
use std::{collections::{BTreeMap}, cmp::Ordering};
use std::ops::Bound::{Included, Unbounded};

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Hash)]
pub enum StringKey {
    Exact(String),
    Any,
}
impl PartialOrd for StringKey {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        match (self, other) {
            (StringKey::Exact(a), StringKey::Exact(b)) => Some(a.cmp(b)),
            (StringKey::Exact(_), StringKey::Any) => Some(Ordering::Equal),
            (StringKey::Any, StringKey::Exact(_)) => Some(Ordering::Equal),
            (StringKey::Any, StringKey::Any) => Some(Ordering::Equal),
        }
    }
}
impl Ord for StringKey {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        self.partial_cmp(other).unwrap()
    }
}
impl PartialEq for StringKey {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        match (self, other) {
            (Self::Exact(a), Self::Exact(b)) => a == b,
            (Self::Exact(_), Self::Any) => true,
            (Self::Any, Self::Exact(_)) => true,
            (Self::Any, Self::Any) => true,
        }
    }
}
impl Eq for StringKey {
}

fn main() {
    let mut map = BTreeMap::new();
    map.insert((StringKey::Exact("a".to_string()), StringKey::Exact("x".to_string())), "ax".to_string());
    map.insert((StringKey::Exact("a".to_string()), StringKey::Exact("y".to_string())), "ay".to_string());
    map.insert((StringKey::Exact("b".to_string()), StringKey::Exact("x".to_string())), "bx".to_string());
    let query = (StringKey::Exact("a".to_string()), StringKey::Any);
    // Would be easier to do (Included(query), Included(query)), but that only returns one item
    let iter = map.range((Included(query.clone()), Unbounded)); 
    for (key, value) in iter {
        if key > &query {
            return;
        }
        println!("{:?} {:?}", key, value);
    }
}
```

Which prints

```
(Exact("a"), Exact("x")) "ax"
(Exact("a"), Exact("y")) "ay"
```

So that works, but the problem is just that I'm violating the Ord/Eq rules here (things like StringKey::Exact("a") == StringKey::Any == StringKey::Exact("b")), which doesn't seem like the right way to go about it. It's also a problem since I'd like to store the StringKey in HashMaps in other parts of the code but that doesn't really work when Eq is implemented like this.

So, again; is there a better way to do this?

Thankful for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current implementation breaks the contract of `Ord`.
This means that the only thing you reliably say about calling `map.range()` is that it will not break memory safety.
The values that are returned by the function, or whether it returns at all instead of panicking, could change in different versions of rust and cannot be relied on.
In short, **you really want your `Ord` implementation to be a total order**.

The best way to solve your problem (which also plays nicely into the interface of `range`) is to have *two* special values - `Min` and `Max`. Then a query for `("a", *)` would effectively translate to `("a", Min) .. ("a", Max)`.

```
use std::{collections::BTreeMap, cmp::Ordering};
use std::ops::Bound::{Included, Unbounded};

#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Hash)]
pub enum StringKey {
    Min,
    Exact(String),
    Max,
}

fn main() {
    let mut map = BTreeMap::new();
    map.insert((StringKey::Exact("a".to_string()), StringKey::Exact("x".to_string())), "ax".to_string());
    map.insert((StringKey::Exact("a".to_string()), StringKey::Exact("y".to_string())), "ay".to_string());
    map.insert((StringKey::Exact("b".to_string()), StringKey::Exact("x".to_string())), "bx".to_string());
    
    let query_min = (StringKey::Exact("a".to_string()), StringKey::Min);
    let query_max = (StringKey::Exact("a".to_string()), StringKey::Max);
    let iter = map.range(query_min..query_max); 
    for (key, value) in iter {
        println!("{:?} {:?}", key, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution!

Comment: Ah smart, that makes much more sense, thanks! And to handle StartsWith; I guess I could do min=Include("Bob") and max=Exclude("Boc") (to get everything on "Bob*")?

Comment: @FredrikNorén Yes, that should work.

Comment: (Oops, I meant Bob -> Bod, i.e. last letter +1)

Answer (score 0):

For **filtering** it may be enough to **match** the tuple pattern.

As a simple example:

```rust
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

fn main() {
    let mut map = BTreeMap::new();
    map.insert(("a", "x"), "ax");
    map.insert(("a", "y"), "ay");
    map.insert(("b", "y"), "by");
    for (k, v) in &map {
        if matches!(k, ("a", _)) {
            println!("{:?} -> {}", k, v);
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5aef6563179c8b9c9edb15432971187e)

The solution with range is more elegant (probably more performant too). But it is also more convoluted. So it will depend on your needs.